# Meteor on Nitrous - Path for Meteor 'Assets'?

Tags: meteor, nitrousio

I wish to read text from a file in my Meteor app.

I am using [Nitrous.io](http://www.nitrous.io)

The app is called 'myApp' and I am using the following code:

```
var data = Assets.getText('myApp/lib/test.txt');
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Unknown asset: /myApp/lib/test.txt
```

What is the correct path to my test.txt file in this context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The path for `getText` is relative to your application's private subdirectory. So if the file was `myApp/private/test.txt`, you could read it with `Assets.getText('test.txt');`. This should be true regardless of the hosting environment.

Answer (score 2):

You can define your path by using the process.env.PWD variable :

```
var base            = process.env.PWD;
var itemsLocation   = base + '/public/items/';
```

It should work on Nitrious.